# NodeJS project waiting after start

Tags: node.js, mongodb, viber

I have a task to transfer project to another server, frow AWS to VMWare.

I changed all credentials, after start code, it successfully conected to MongoDB and waiting.....without some result.
/var/log/mondodb - connection successfull

Config Mongo Connect:

```
var moment = require('moment');
var request = require('request'); 
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var fs = require('fs');

var logFile = fs.createWriteStream('./mongo-connections.log', {flags : 'a'});

var user = '***';
var password = '*****';
var uri = `mongodb://${user}:${password}@127.0.0.1`;
var client = new MongoClient(uri); 

async function run() {
  try {
    logFile.write('Подключение к: ' + uri + '\\');  

    await client.connect();

    console.log('Подключение к базе MongoDB установлено');

    var users = client.db('users');
    var users2 = client.db('users2');
    var local_oplog_rs = client.db('local_oplog_rs');
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    logFile.write(`Ошибка подключения к ${uri}: ${err} \n`);
  } finally {
    await client.close();
  }
}

run().catch(console.dir);
```

On the AWS mongo-connect code was sync-mode, I changed to assync-mode.
When I use sync-mode, connection error: Topology is closed